# VS C# Targeting and testing older .NET Framework

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, virtual-machine

I'm currently working on a C# app. Its current target framework is .NET framework 4.8, however my customer told me he has only 4.7.03190 installed and is not willing to upgrade it. Therefore, I need to downgrade the version on the app.

I tried switching the taget framework to 4.7 in the project settings and compiled it without any problems, however according to the customer it still doesn't work for him. Therefore, I ask myself these questions:

1. Am I missing a setting that I need to tweak?
2. I noticed that in packages.config, the packages targeted higher framework versions (4.7.2 or 4.8). I reinstalled them and now they say 4.7. Might this have been the issue?
3. Is there any reliable way to test whether the app will run on a system with a lower .NET framework version? Initaially, I wanted to use a VM but Windows 11 seems to come with a built-in 4.8 that I cannot uninstall or change.

I appreciate any help you can offer me. Thank you for reading!

Comment: _"however my customer told me he has only 4.7.03190 installed and is not willing to upgrade it"_ - what's their excuse? ...I'd love to hear it, because there simply isn't one (there are zero breaking-changes I'm aware-of and 4.8's system-requirements are the same as 4.7's, including support for Windows 7).

Comment: _"however according to the customer it still doesn't work for him."_ - **don't guess**: just ask him what _specifically_ isn't working, and to send-over error-logs (e.g. WIndows' _Application_ event-log, by default, contains exception-details and stack-traces of all fatal exceptions in .NET programs).

Comment: Are they sure they haven't already upgraded? .NET Framework upgrades are pushed through Windows Update. All 4.x versions are binary replacements which means they replace any previous versions and can't be downgraded. Assuming the OS doesn't already have 4.8 installed out of the box

Comment: No.   If the app is using HTTPS (encrypted) there a a number of different reasons the encryption will not work before 4.7.1.  Also older OS may not support new encryption modes that is used with TLS 1.3.

Comment: The customer doesn't really have a plausible excuse, he is simply afraid of his system collapsing. I don't think I'm able to talk him out of it. He has sent me a screenshot of the registry of his server which definetely shows 4.7.0.  Apprently, whenever he wants to start his app it simply says he needs 4.8 at least. There is no HTTPS involved.

Comment: Why would they be afraid of their system-collapsing from an update that's already been out for years? (and what's so special about 4.8? ...why didn't they have this complaint about the 4.7 update?) And even if the update _might_ break things (it won't), they have a set of verified full backups and a disaster-recovery plan, right? _...right_?

Comment: I don't think there is any logicial reasoning behind this. The customer seems to live up to the 'never change a winning team' rule. I've noticed this while discussing other questions. At this point I've accepted it as it is and try to figure my way around it.

Comment: Hello, did your customer tell you what exactly does "doesn't work" here mean? Did Visaul Studio or Windows report any errors?

Comment: Hey, as I mentioned that downgrading isn't as easy as he thought, it apparently convinced him to upgrade his system. Thanks nonetheless!

Comment: @Theatralica Phew, I’m relieved to hear that